# SWIFT: Button is not disappearing on click

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

When a UIButton in my UITableViewCell is clicked, I'd like it to disappear.  I've tried a number of suggestions from other Stack Overflow posts, but I get the same error: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".

Below is a screenshot of the view controller and my code:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why don't you just make the button invisible?

Comment: You don't need var for `voteButtonLabel`. Try to replace the error line with `sender.hidden = true`

Comment: Yes, you can hide it...as said by anhtu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a var for voteButtonLabel, you can remove it. 
Just need to replace the error line with `sender.hidden = true`

Change function to `voteButton(sender:UIButton)`

Comment: Thanks.  I did that, and now I'm getting the error "Value of type 'AnyObject has no member 'hidden'"

Comment: @SB2015 Change sender type from `AnyObject` to `UIButton`. As I edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your button voteButtonLabel is linked to the storyboard outlet, your error is usually thrown in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just don't want to give the user the possibility to vote again so you can just hide it. Or do you want to achieve something special with removing it completely?
Try:

```
voteBuoonLabel.hidden = true
```